# Using SSHFS on a Mac with a password-protected private key

Tags: macos, ssh, sshfs

Hey guys, I have a remote fileserver that I use to host my music/movies. I have a laptop and desktop, and wanted to share my files between the two, *without* the files actually being on either machine, so I employed an old dying laptop to host an SSH server, plugged into my external drive.

I have sshd configured on the server to accept connections using my password-protected private key, and it works great using applications like Cyberduck. The problem is, I want to be able to open iTunes and point it to my remote library. (Obviously iTunes would only work while the share is mounted.) Similarly, if I want to watch a movie, I don't want to have to copy it to my desktop, wait for the transfer to finish, then start watching. I want to double-click the file, and have it stream to my laptop as if it were a local file.

The problem is, I tried installing sshfs from this site:

[sshfs for Mac OS X](http://pqrs.org/macosx/sshfs/)

But I can't figure out how to provide a private key, let alone a password-protected one. I'm new to SSH server configuration, so if I'm leaving out any crucial information, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might first want to use the *standard* `sshfs` for OS X which is included with MacFuse [here](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS).  Using that, it supports reading the `$HOME/.ssh/config` and ssh keys just like the standard command line `ssh` client.  Try getting a connection working with `ssh` client and then use the same username and host name for the sshfs mount.  I use exactly this setup with iTunes for accessing my music library remotely.  However, if the machines involved are both OS X systems and on the same network (so that `Bonjour` discovery works), current versions of `iTunes` allow automatic sharing of music libraries, as long as you are willing to keep `iTunes` running on both.  See `iTunes -> Preferences -> Sharing`.

Comment: That worked, I had to let it sit for a few minutes the first time. Not sure why, but now it works great! Thanks!